# NSPredicate for String length dependency

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I am trying to filter an array from another array below is my code snippet

```
NSMutableArray *filteredArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
    [wordsArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
     {
         NSString *currentWord = (NSString *)obj;
         if(([currentWord length]>=4 && [currentWord length]<=6) && [currentWord rangeOfString:@" "].location == NSNotFound)
         {
             [filteredArray addObject:currentWord];
         }
     }];
```

My code is perfectly works as I expected. I feel using `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` is more optimized solution than my code. How can I write NSPredicate for my code?

I followed many questions but none of the questions are giving me accurate answer to replace `[currentWord length]>=4 && [currentWord length]<=6) && [currentWord rangeOfString:@" "].location == NSNotFound` with NSPredicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a predicate like:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"length >= 4 AND length <= 6 AND NOT SELF CONTAINS ' '"];
```

Comment: Thanks Wain, It's perfectly working. Can you suggest me some reference to learn Predicate related stuff.

Comment: Apple guide is https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001798-SW1

Answer (score 2):

With a predicate its a cleaner solution. But it is not faster (you said optimized). Even when you reuse the predicate!

I wrote a little test for my 2GHz i7 MacBook Pro. The solution:
1.000.000 times filtering an array:

- Everytime a new predicate: 39.694 seconds
- Reuse predicate: 17.784 seconds
- Your code: 2.174 seconds

big difference, isn't it?

Here is my test code:

```
@implementation Test
- (void)test1
{
    int x = 0;
    NSArray *array = @[@"a", @"bb", @"ccc", @"dddd", @"eeeee", @"ffffff", @"ggggggg", @"hh hh", @"ii  ii"];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"length >= 4 AND length <= 6 AND NOT self CONTAINS ' '"];
        x += [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate].count;
    }
    NSLog(@"%d", x);
}

- (void)test2
{
    int x = 0;
    NSArray *array = @[@"a", @"bb", @"ccc", @"dddd", @"eeeee", @"ffffff", @"ggggggg", @"hh hh", @"ii  ii"];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"length >= 4 AND length <= 6 AND NOT self CONTAINS ' '"];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        x += [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate].count;
    }
    NSLog(@"%d", x);
}

- (void)test3
{
    int x = 0;
    NSArray *array = @[@"a", @"bb", @"ccc", @"dddd", @"eeeee", @"ffffff", @"ggggggg", @"hh hh", @"ii  ii"];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
        NSMutableArray *filteredArray = [NSMutableArray array];
        [array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
         {
             NSString *currentWord = (NSString *)obj;
             if(([currentWord length]>=4 && [currentWord length]<=6) && [currentWord rangeOfString:@" "].location == NSNotFound)
             {
                 [filteredArray addObject:currentWord];
            }
         }];
        x += filteredArray.count;
    }
    NSLog(@"%d", x);
}
```

Comment: How would it behave over a large data set enumerated only once? Also, how would it perform relative to predicateWithBlock:?

Comment: Tested with 10.000 random strings with length between 0 and 9 letters. Each test repeats 10.000 times. Creating predicate each time: 165.828 seconds, reuse predicate: 167.147 seconds, enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: 20.235 seconds, and filteredArrayUsingPredicate: 23.974 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Here for my opinion most clear solution in Swift

```
NSPredicate(format: "str >= %@", ".{5}")
```